# Calling a value starting with $ character in Oracle

Tags: oracle, substring, trim

Let's say you have a table called **Employee** and one of the *employee names* begins or includes the [$] or [#] sign within the String, like Hel$lo or like #heLLo. How can you call the value?

Is it possible to select and trim the value in a single command?

Kind regards

Comment: huh?  What to you mean "call the value?"  Please show expected output

Comment: I meant search for the value that begins with $ or #. I tried searching using LIKE "%$", it triggered an error. And is there a way to search for it if the symbol located in the middle of the word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select the names, but with special characters $ and # removed, you can use the TRANSLATE function. Add more characters to the list if you need to.

```
select translate(name, 'A$#', 'A') from employee;
```

The function will "translate" the character 'A' to itself, '$' and '#' to nothing (simply removing them from the string), and it will leave all other characters - other than A, $ and # - unchanged. It may seem odd that you need the 'A' in this whole business; and you really don't need 'A' specifically, but you do need some character that you want to *keep*. The reason for that is Oracle's idiotic handling of `null`; don't worry about the reason, just remember the technique.

You may need to remove characters but you don't know in advance what they will be. That can be done too, but you need to be careful not to remove legitimate characters, like the dot (A. C. Green), dash (John Connor-Smith), apostrophe (Betty O'Rourke) etc. You can then do it either with regular expressions (easy to write, but not the most efficient) or with TRANSLATE as above (it looks uglier, but it will run faster). Something like this:

```
select regexp_replace(name, [^[:alpha:].'-]) from employee
```

This will replace any character that is **not** "alpha" (letters) or one of the characters specifically enumerated (dot, apostrophe, dash) with nothing, effectively removing them. Note that dash has a special meaning in character classes, so it **must** be the last one in the enumeration.

If you need to make the changes in the table itself, you can use an `update` statement, using TRANSLATE or REGEXP_REPLACE as shown above.